# Getting latest build of Puppet agent for ARM

Tags: puppet

Im planning to use Puppet to maintain 100-1000 ARM based Debian machines for a multi-year study. The puppet 'master' system has v3.3 (obtained via yum on CentOS 6.4). The client systems are on v 2.6 (via apt-get on Debian 6). I need to update these to get the latest Facter, etc.

I tried to add the puppet labs repository (apt.puppetlabs.com) but when I go to install I'm told there are no ARM binaries available. Same if I download the appropriate .DEB files and try `dpkg -i` with them.

What are my options for getting this update?

Comment: Build it yourself?

Comment: Was looking into that. The files (appear) to be all ruby so it should be a matter of copying rather than building. Tracking down all the dependencies is a killer though.

Comment: @ethrbunny, it shouldn't be.  Since you are running debian, just visit the puppet package page.  Where you can download a **Debian source package** in addition to getting a list of all the package dependencies and build dependencies.  Use one of the many Internet guides you can find online that describe how to backport Debian packages.  http://packages.debian.org/sid/puppet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about installing from the gem package?  See [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/installation.html#installing-from-gems-not-recommended).

Comment: Looks like there are .tar.gz packages available there too. I'll give this avenue a try.